# I'm having problems with dataTables and my buttons in the pagination

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I have a button inside a datatable that open a modal, when I go to dataTable's second page the button doesn't work and the modal is not open.

this is my button code:

```
<td><a href="#modalEdit" id="editMod" class="waves-effect waves-light btn blue lighten-1 modal-trigger"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
```

and I'm trying the delegate events but when I click my button it send me in console: Uncaught ReferenceError: clickLink is not defined.

Here is my delegate event:

```
$('#table').on('click', '#editMod', function(){
            clickLink(this);
            return false;
        });
```

Thank you!

EDITED:

```
<table id="table" class="highlight mdl-data-table" width="100%">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th id="titulo">Something</th>
                  <th id="titulo">Edit</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                  <td>Somethingl</td>
                  <td><a href="#modal3" id="editMod" class="waves-effect waves-light btn blue lighten-1 modal-trigger"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>                 
              </tr>
           </tbody>
</table>

<div id="modal3" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
  <table id="table_p">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Something</th>
              <th>Edited</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td>aquí va el nombre del producto a editar</td>
              <td>aquí la descripción a editar</td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: where is clickLink defined? How is it defined?

Comment: You have a call to clickLink in your click event. Where is this clickLink? If you dont know where is this then it absolutely is undefined. Either comment this line or create a method for this

Answer (score 0):

This is the code mentioned above

```
$('#table').on('click', '#editMod', function(){
        **clickLink(this);**
        return false;
    });
```

In this code there is a reference to clickLink(this). When the javascript compiler compiles the code it first looks for the definition if this method exists. Since this method doesn't exists anywhere you are getting a self explanatory error - that this method is undefined. To fix this - Please either define this method in your code or comment this line to test if your code works as expected.

Hope this be of some help.

Happy Learning :)

Comment: Can you please share your full code snippet? It is getting confusing